# Authenticating Dynamics CRM Online with Facebook Login

Tags: facebook, azure, dynamics-crm, facebook-login, dynamics-crm-online

I am using Microsoft Dynamics CRM Online and I want my users to be able to log in using Facebook Login. I imagine the user going to the website. If the user's already authenticated with Facebook, he gets access to the CRM system. If not, he will be redericted to a Facebook login box. He would have to authenticate with Facebook to get access to the CRM Online instance.

I guess, I would need to set up an ACS to do this. What else would I need?
Which components would I need to set up and how would they all work together?

I was not able to find any documentation about this topic.

Thank you!

Comment: Are you wanting to give them access to the CRM Front end, or to be able to make SDK calls?

Comment: I want them to access the CRM front end by signing in with their Facebook account instead of ADFS or their Office 365 account.

Comment: Not supported.  It would be nice though...

Comment: Thank you. So, there's absolutely no way, right?

Comment: I am not an Authentication expert, but the only way to actually log into CRM online is via one of the supported Microsoft options.  Unless there is some much that can be performed with Federated Services, but I thought that was only for AD.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to properly authenticate the user(Valid Office365 User) on the portal.office.com before proceeding to CRM ... that's the way it is built, I guess you will not have a way to escape it.

There are multiple Microsoft Dynamics CRM Online identity providers that must be accounted for when you develop an application that connects to the Organization or Discovery web services. These providers can be identified as managed domain, federated, and Microsoft account. This topic focuses on Microsoft Dynamics CRM Online web service authentication with managed domain and federated identity providers, although the same classes and code shown here also work with all supported identity providers and Microsoft Dynamics CRM deployment types.

Here is some more details about it :

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh670628.aspx